# Delegate External User Administration functionally (Partner community Users)

Tags: community, partner-communities

Delegate External User Administration functionlly not working i have assign one user as a delegate admin to other Profile users. when  i login as a Delegated admin user in Community i am not able to see the Manage External Users Button on other users. So that i can change password or deactive users.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Manage External Users" button is only available in classic for internal users. 
In Lightning, as a delegated external user admin, you should have "Enable {Partner, Community} User".